# How to make a grouped bar chart from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

How can I use pyplot to plot this dataframe:

```
          Team   Boys  Girls
0        Sharks    5       5
1         Lions    3       7

data = {'Team': ['Sharks', 'Lions'], 'Boys': [5, 5], 'Girls': [5, 6] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

so that I can end up with something like this where there are two bars per team that denote the boys/girls.
[image]

It seems to be a messy process with pyplot, so if there is an easier way I am all ears.

Comment: `df.set_index('Team').plot.bar()`

Comment: I found that duplicate question by typing `[python] grouped bar` into the search bar and clicking the first result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with `rot=0` to rotate the xticks

```
df.set_index('Team').plot.bar(rot = 0)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]